# GWT LDAP access denied

Tags: security, gwt, ldap, access-denied

I am trying to establish a connection to a ldap in gwt. Thanks to a former post
( [GWT JDBC LDAP connection fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383981/gwt-jdbc-ldap-connection-fails) ) I was able to at least contact that server. However, even though I put in the correct cn/uid and password the access is denied. I get following exception:

> java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.net.SocketPermission IP:PORT connect,resolve)

I know that my login name and password are correct because I was able to access the ldap via JXplorer and checked it. Could App Engine be the problem? And if so, how can I test my application when using App Engine is disabled?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

you mentioned that you are developing for app engine.

On app engine you are not allowed to open a socket by yourself (your exception occurs because of this restriction.) If you want to setup a connection to your ldap you have to wrap your ldap call as HTTP and use it with the url fetch service. If the ldap is inside your company you can use google secure data connector to have a https connection from app engine to your internal network.

Comment: I think you meant "not allowed" instead of "now allowed".

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing for app engine, i dont think you can connect to LDAP or JDBC or anything TCP/IP, apart from what app engine offers as API.

Answer (score 0):

LDAP requires sockets (TCP port 389) and AppEngine does not support sockets.